# How do you have multiple Add Access Policy in ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to conditionally add Access Policies to a Key Vault and the problem is that you can't have more than 1 resource in the template with the name of KeyVault/accessPolicies/add

This is effectively what I want to achieve:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "vaultName": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "condition": "[parameters('someCondition')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('vaultName'), '/add')]",
            "apiVersion": "2016-10-01",
            "properties": {
                "accessPolicies": [
                    {
                        "tenantId": "[if(parameters('someCondition'), reference(variables('someAppServiceResourceId'), '2015-08-31-PREVIEW').tenantId, json('null'))]",
                        "objectId": "[if(parameters('someCondition'), reference(variables('someAppServiceResourceId'), '2015-08-31-PREVIEW').principalId, json('null'))]",
                        "permissions": {
                            "keys": ["all"],
                            "secrets": ["all"],
                            "certificates": ["all"],
                            "storage": ["all"]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "condition": "[parameters('otherCondition')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('vaultName'), '/add')]",
            "apiVersion": "2016-10-01",
            "properties": {
                "accessPolicies": [
                    {
                        "tenantId": "[if(parameters('otherCondition'), reference(variables('someOTHERAppServiceResourceId'), '2015-08-31-PREVIEW').tenantId, json('null'))]",
                        "objectId": "[if(parameters('otherCondition'), reference(variables('someOTHERAppServiceResourceId'), '2015-08-31-PREVIEW').principalId, json('null'))]",
                        "permissions": {
                            "keys": ["all"],
                            "secrets": ["all"],
                            "certificates": ["all"],
                            "storage": ["all"]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {
    }
}
```

However I can only have one resource in this deployment by the name of 'KeyVaultName/add'.

I was thinking I could conditionally build the array of access policies in variables and do some array concatenation, but it won't work since I use the reference() function inside the access policy to go and fetch the tenant and principal ID.

Comment: have you tried nested templates ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/linked-templates#nested-template

Comment: Working on testing that approach now to see if it cures it!

Comment: Did you end up finding an answer? I'm having the exact same issue now

Comment: Don't see how nested templates would help here as the conflict is at the resource level. Actually other than the hack suggested by @14207973 there doesn't really seem to be any way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

why do you think this would not work?

```
"properties": {
    "copy": [
        {
            "name": "accessPolicies",
            "count": "[xxx]",
            "input": {
                "tenantId": "[if(parameters('otherCondition'), reference(variables('someOTHERAppServiceResourceId'), '2015-08-31-PREVIEW').tenantId, json('null'))]",
                "objectId": "[if(parameters('otherCondition'), reference(variables('someOTHERAppServiceResourceId'), '2015-08-31-PREVIEW').principalId, json('null'))]",
                "permissions": {
                    "keys": ["all"],
                    "secrets": ["all"],
                    "certificates": ["all"],
                    "storage": ["all"]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I think that will fail when there are 0 items in the count, which is a scenario that will happen for us.

Comment: just put a condition on the resource so that it skips this resource when the count is 0, so it would work. also I think they fixed 0 count for copies error, but I'm not sure. anyway, condition will always work

Comment: This is so close, but unfortunately 0 count still seems to be an issue!

Comment: your api-version is outdated. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/copy-properties#copy-limits

Answer (score 0):

`"accessPolicies"` takes an array, which allows you to specify multiple policies through a single resource. You can have the policies within the same array applied conditionally, using `if` expressions similar to what you're already doing. I've found that `json('null')` causes deployment errors for me. Instead, when the condition is not met, I use an empty GUID, `'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'`, and assign an empty set of permissions, effectively making it a no-op.

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",

  "variables": {
    "keyVaultNoPermissions": { },
    "keyVaultAllPermissions": {
      "keys": ["all"],
      "secrets": ["all"],
      "certificates": ["all"],
      "storage": ["all"]
    }
  },

  "resources": [
    // ...
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies",
      "apiVersion": "2016-10-01",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('keyVaultName'), '/add')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[parameters('keyVaultName')]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "accessPolicies": [
          {
            "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
            "objectId": "[if(parameters('someCondition'), reference(variables('someAppServiceResourceId'), '2015-08-31-PREVIEW').principalId, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')]",
            "permissions": "[if(parameters('someCondition'), variables('keyVaultAllPermissions'), variables('keyVaultNoPermissions'))]"
          },
          {
            "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
            "objectId": "[if(parameters('otherCondition'), reference(variables('someOTHERAppServiceResourceId'), '2015-08-31-PREVIEW').principalId, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')]",
            "permissions": "[if(parameters('otherCondition'), variables('keyVaultAllPermissions'), variables('keyVaultNoPermissions'))]"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```